# How to put a multiplication sign in the xlabel in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to set the xlabel in gnuplot to:

```
   population ( "times" 1000 )
```

Here the "times" should be replaced by an actual multiplication sign. I want a png output.

Is there a way to use the $\times$ as in latex?

Comment: Do you mean utf8 00D7 character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your terminal understands UTF-8.
So, simply put it in as text. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign)

```
population ( ⋅ 1000 )
```

or

```
population ( × 1000 )
```

Comment: I rellay don't know how to use UTF-8 in gnuplot. Can you suggest me some other source for this?

Comment: just copy & paste the text above into gnuplot or your text editor.

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks.

Comment: if the answer is acceptable then please mark it as such. With this, your question will appear as answered.